# Hidden window using javascript

Tags: javascript, window, hidden

Just wanted to know if it is possible to create a hidden window using javascript?

Comment: Regarding the question, what's your goal? If you want to send data to the server without user seeing something, simply use AJAX.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create an iframe

```
var element = document.createElement("iframe"); 
element.setAttribute('id', 'myframe');
document.body.appendChild(element);
```

You can hide an iframe by setting its width and height to zero or by setting its visibility to hidden in the stylesheet.

Comment: Actually `element.style.display = "none";` is the ideal way to have it hidden as far as I know.

Comment: I've read on  someone's blog that iframe may not work properly if we set display to none, but it were not mentioned in what case exactly. Maybe you're right :)

Answer (score 11):

You can also create a new window visible only in taskbar with this workaround:

```
window.open(path.html,'_blank', 'toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,left=10000, top=10000, width=10, height=10, visible=none', '');
```

that open a window in a position not visible by user. I have used this trick different times.

Comment: I tried this in IE10, i dont know why it didnt worked for me....will give it another try

Comment: Try to play with position left and right. I used 10000 as random big number. How did you see the windows in IE10?

Comment: Does not work on MacOS

Comment: Does not work anymore, probably for good reasons

Answer (score 0):

Under IE 9+ you can create a window off-screen:

```
var options = "left=" + (screen.width*2) + ",top=0";
var myWin = window.open(url, name, options);
// Hide the window - IE only
myWin.blur();
// Show the window - IE only
myWin.focus();
```

screen.width is your monitor width.  Using "*2" allows for users with dual monitors.

This does not work under Chrome.