# Hiding pop-up window opened by URL (pinging URL without page redirect)

Tags: javascript, html, url, telephony

I'm currently working on a computer telephone integration system which connects phone handsets to a web interface. A call can be made from the SNOM handset using the http command: "`http://admin:password@[phone ip address]/command.htm?number=[phonenumber]`". This works correctly, except it opens a new window which redirects to the SNOM index page - I'm trying to stop this redirect but still enable the call to be made.

Instead of entering the URL directly into the browser I have a link which the user can press to start the call:

```
<a target="popup" onclick="dial()">Dial</a>
```

The link calls the dial() function which uses window.open() which is passed the corresponding url.

Here are the things I've tried to "hide" or disguise the newly opened tab:

- using window.open() then implementing a timeout of x milliseconds, then closing the tab using .close()
  => the page opened and dialled the number but didn't close
- using window.document.open().write() to change the contents of the SNOM index page so it said 'Dialling Number' => This correctly rewrites the page so atleast it disguises the pop up but it changes the url to about:blank and the handset doesn't dial
- using window.blur() or setting the window "left"/"top" parameter to 10000 to move it off the page => this didn't work either, it just moved it into the corner.
- applying iframe to hide the frame => this caused further errors
- I tried numerous AJAX forms/methods and I didn't get very far.

To try and solve this, I visited the following stackoverflow links:

- [Make a ping to a url without redirecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44060938/make-a-ping-to-a-url-without-redirecting)
- [Hidden window using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180684/hidden-window-using-javascript)
- [sending an url but staying on the same page ( php, codeigniter, javascript )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085388/sending-an-url-but-staying-on-the-same-page-php-codeigniter-javascript)

In short, I need to be able to call the URL - "`http://admin:password@[phone ip address]/command.htm?number=[phonenumber]`" and to either hide the pop-up, close the pop up immediately but still make the call, or rewrite the page so it disguises it.

Here is the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests"> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<style>

a {
  padding:.5em;
  background-color:rgb(55,55,55);
  color:white;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-weight:lighter;
  cursor:pointer;
}

</style>

<body>

Call Number

<br>
<input name = 'number' id = 'number' type = 'number'>
<br><br>
<a target="popup" onclick="dial()">Dial</a>

</body>

<script>   

function dial() {

  var num = $('#number').val();

  str1 = 'http://admin:password@[ip address]/command.htm?number=9'
  var url = str1.concat(num);


  var x = window.open(url,'_blank', 'toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,left=-20000, top=20000, width=10, height=10, visible=none').blur();


/*
w.document.open().getElementById('body').innerHTML="<body fontFamily = 'Raleway' bgColor='red' text='white'><table><tr><td><img src= 'https://www.sexologistdoctorindelhi.com/images/call.gif' style = 'height:120px;margin-left:-40px;margin-right:-30px;margin-top:-20px;'</td><td><h1 style = 'margin-top: -15px;'> Dialling</h1><p style = 'margin-top:-20px;'> "+num+"</p></td><title>WWS</title></body>";
*/
  
}
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Is putting `visibility: hidden;` on the popup an option here?

Comment: you can set visibility to none, but this didn't seem to have any effect. I think in new browsers some of the documentation or methods are outdated. Here is a link to the window object: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp

Comment: visibility:hidden does not work :(

Comment: Hmm, is an iframe an option instead of window object?

Answer (score 0):

If an iframe is an option for you then you can simply set `height` and `width` of the `iframe` to 0, or it's visibility to `hidden`.

Comment: Hi Tenma, thanks for the fast response. The window.open line minimises the window to a small box but does not remove it. This is something I tried and was confused by, I thought it was because I was on microsoft edge, but it also doesnt work on firefox and chrome. I will look into iFrame now

Comment: I was hopeful that iFrame would work, but it returned an error stating "subresource is blocked" since there are credentials in the URL itself. Supposedly, chrome does not allow URLs with credentials to be posted in frames of web pages.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about the user credentials in your URL. There may be a workaround for iframe but it may be more trouble than it's worth. - Maybe playing with window position is your better bet? I'm not near a PC at the moment but will test some things later tonight.

Comment: So after more research, I have realized the window position method does not work anymore. Or if it does, it's very limited. - I did find this post about the iframe method, however, it is dated a bit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37483956/how-to-pass-credentials-to-iframe-using-javascript  - Still worth a shot? Didn't realize this was a common issue.